# Is it possible to implement a trigger (or sth. similar) to detect an event

Tags: pipelinedb

I have a continous view based on a stream. In the CV some data is aggregated (e.g. average and maximum value of the last 2 minutes). Is it possible to implement a trigger (or sth. similar) to detect an event, such as the max. value increases above a threshold and do further action in case of this event?

Answer (score 0):

Currently that is only possible with PipelineDB's commercial offering.

Comment: Thanks Derek for clrafication. Does "currently" mean, that perhaps this will eventually make it to the non-commercial branch?